# Change echo value from Checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I implemented some checkboxes in the frontend of a wordpress site to get some information from a registered user. I always asked them for example: "Are you a Designer?" or "Are you a Actor?" and set a checkbox beneath so they can check it or let it unchecked.

The Checkbox Code looks like:

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="new_user_designer" id="new_user_designer"  value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(  "new_user_designer", $userdata->ID )) == "true") echo "checked";  ?> />
```

I save the Checkbox input with:

```
if ($_POST['new_user_designer'] != $user_info->new_user_designer)
    update_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'new_user_designer', sanitize_text_field($_POST['new_user_designer']));
```

So far, everything works great! But here is my Problem and i need your help.
I will echo the checkbox value in the Authorbox of the user. I tried this code:

```
<?php echo $user_info->new_user_designer; ?>
```

The above code works to show the correct Checkbox status for each user, BUT it returns
the value "true". Now, how can i change the output "true" to "Designer" or any custom word...???
Again, so if a user checks the Checkbox it should show Designer in the Author Box instead of only "true"?

Second Question:

If there is a solution for my first Question, i need some help to show multiple checked inputs from 2 or more checkboxes in a row if some user checks more than one checkbox. For example the user is a Designer and Actor, he checks 2 checkboxes and now it should show in the user Info Box:

Designer, Actor

Comment: Um, you're setting `value="true"` yourself on the input element. Does your code still work if you change that to whatever you want?

Comment: Hi mabi, i tried to change the value="true" to value="Designer" but then the checkbox don´t show up checked after saving the changes. But with this change the output shows me "Designer" instead of "true"..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you should change code below

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="new_user_designer" id="new_user_designer"  value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(  "new_user_designer", $userdata->ID )) == "true") echo "checked";  ?> />
```

To

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="new_user_designer" id="new_user_designer"  value="Designer" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(  "new_user_designer", $userdata->ID )) == "Designer"){ echo "checked";}  ?> />
```

Comment: Hi Ram Sharma, i tried your suggestion to but then the checkbox don´t show up checked after saving the changes...

Comment: @NewUser Can you show us what `get_the_author_meta(  "new_user_designer", $userdata->ID )` outputs? Maybe it's not storing/retrieving your value correctly?

Comment: @mabi <?php echo get_the_author_meta( "new_user_designer", $userdata->ID ) ?>  outputs the word: true and that looks fine, because the Designer Checkbox is checked. When i uncheck the checkbox it shows nothing.

Comment: @NewUser does it show "true" when you make the change Ram suggested? With the code you posted it should show "Designer" and thus match the condition, making the box checked (don't know if `esc_attr` does some fancy lowercasing?).

Comment: When i change both "true" to "designer" in lower case it looks like it works. it outputs "designer". I will make some tests. But with uppercase it does not work! Any idea to my second Q? thx